# I have an input statement but I want it to count how many whole numbers were entered, words can also be entered into this input

Tags: python

**I want to enter a range of numbers and words and have all postive whole numbers to be counted

This is what my output should look like

e.g.

How many strings do you want to enter: 4

Enter string 1: 57

Enter string 2: 4

Enter string 3: -22

Enter string 4: cow

No of positive whole numbers entered: 2

This is my current code I have wrote **

```py
def main():
    string=int(input("How many strings do you want to enter? "))

    for num in range(1,string+1):
        value=float(input("Enter string %a: "%num))
        print("No of positive whole numbers entered is:",IsPos(val)) 
        

def IsPos(val):
    counterVal=0;

    for whole_number in value:

        if val.is_integer() and val>=0:
            counterVal+=1

    return counterval;

main()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Does your code show any error or exception? I'm trying to figure out what's your question. The code seems right, I guess your problem is the `float` conversion when the input is not a number?

Comment: Read it as a string (`value=input("Enter string %a: "%num)`), then determine if it is a number or text.

Comment: line 6, in main
    print("No of positive whole numbers entered is:",IsPos(val))
NameError: name 'val' is not defined. Did you mean: 'eval'?                                              
                                                                                                                                    
This is the error that I am receiving

Comment: @Jonny Mopp that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try`/`except` block:

```
def main():
    num = int(input("How many strings do you want to enter? "))
    count = 0
    for i in range(num):
        try:
            if float(input(f"Enter string {i+1}: ")) >= 0:
                count +=1
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print(f"No of positive whole numbers entered is: {count}")
```

output:

```
How many strings do you want to enter? 3
Enter string 1: 1
Enter string 2: -1
Enter string 3: cow
No of positive whole numbers entered is: 1
```

Comment: do I have get rid of Def IsPos(Val) or keep it

Comment: You do not need it, my code is self sufficient ;)

Comment: is there another way I can do it other than the try and except or will I encounter errors if I I did it other ways

Comment: You can manually check the characters as you did, but I feel the try/except is more pythonic

Comment: would you have a solution for my way, just would like to see the difference for future reference